# Intel 8086 - Program Locks Up After Entering a Number

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I'm really new to Assembly Language and I'm working on an assignment that is suppose to ask you to enter a number, either until you type in a zero or until you type in nine numbers, store them on the stack, and then add up the numbers when you're done inputting numbers, and print the sum to the screen. When I assemble and tlink the program and its external files, it does not come up with any errors; however, when I run the code, it prints a blank line (and nothing else), lets me enter one number, locks up, and closes DOSBox. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong and how to fix it, but I'm completely stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    count db 0
    sum dw 0
    prompt db 0ah, 0dh, 'Enter Value ', '$'
    colon db ': ','$'
    reply db 0ah, 0dh, 'Sum Equals: ', '$'
.code
    extrn indec: proc
    extrn outdec: proc
    include myMacros.asm

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov cx,0
    mov bx,0
    
    push cx
    ;jmp L1
    
L1:
    inc count
    prtStr prompt
    mov cl,count
    writeCh count
    prtStr colon
    call indec
    cmp ax,0
    je S
    push ax
    cmp cx,9
    jl L1
    
S:
    pop dx
    add bx,dx
    cmp dx,0
    jne S

    ;prtStr reply
    mov ax,bx
    call outdec
    exit
    
endp
    
end
```

Comment: As a start, you should probably take a look at your code in mymacros.asm.  Just based on the name, I'm guessing `outdec` isn't intended to display strings.  More likely it takes the value in al, converts it to a string and shows it.  So doing `mov al,prompt; call outdec` isn't going to do what you intend.

Comment: So now it prints a blank line, lets me input a number, and then it won't let me type anything else in, but it doesn't close DOSBox and the cursor keeps blinking, so making the changes you said helped, thank you! I'm guessing that my problem now lies somewhere in L1, but I'm not sure. Do you have any other suggestions on what to fix?

Comment: When fixing programs, it generally works best to fix them in the order they occur. Sometimes the reason you get (serious) problem #5 is because (not very serious) problem #1 is mucking things up. If you still aren't getting the prompts, you should probably track that down.  If you plan on learning assembler (or really any programming language), you need to learn how to use a debugger.  I'm not familiar with the assembler you're using, but I suspect the debugger would show you something strange happen at `mov cl,count`.  What if instead of keeping the count in both data and cx, you just use cx?

Comment: I  can recommend Turbo Debugger 2.01 which works well with 16bit executables in DOSBox: https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall99/V22.0201-002/debug.html

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> include myMacros.asm
> ```

Because you don't show these macro's, we can but speculate about how they operate.
However seeing that you zero the `BX` and `CX` registers (that the rest of the code depends on) very early (too early) in the program, I guess that one or more of those `call`'s and macro-invokations could potentionally be changing these registers.

One error is obvious though. If the macro *writeCh* does indeed write a **Ch**aracter, then you should store a suitable ASCII code in the *count* variable. Now you have the numbers [1,9] where you want the characters ["1","9"] that correspond to the ASCII codes [49,57].

```
.data
    count db '0'       ; This is a character '0' with ASCII code 48
    ...
.code
    ...
    push    0          ; Sentinel (*)
L1:
    prtStr  prompt
    inc     count
    writeCh count
    prtStr  colon
    call    indec      ; -> AX
    test    ax, ax
    jz      S
    push    ax
    cmp     count, '9' ; Loose the dependency on the CX register
    jb      L1         ; Treat ASCII code as UNsigned numbers
    
S:
    xor     ax, ax     ; Setup close to the consumer and as late as you can. This will
S_:                    ; improve readability and probably avoid errors too...
    pop     dx
    add     ax, dx
    test    dx, dx     ; Got to sentinel ?
    jnz     S_         ; Not yet

    push    ax         ; In case 'prtStr' clobbers AX
    prtStr  Reply
    pop     ax
    call    outdec
    ...
```

(*) If your reference to [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) in the title is a strict one, then this `push 0` has to be replaced by the pair `xor ax, ax` `push ax`.